# Path Priority in RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I already opened an issue for that [here.](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11616) But also i want to ask it to stackoverflow people.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/xxx")
public class MyController {

@RequestMapping("/**")
public ModelAndView getPage() {
   //some code
}

@RequestMapping("/**/yyy/")
public ModelAndView getPageSecond() {
   //some code
}

@RequestMapping("/**/yyy/{pathVariable}")
public ModelAndView getPageThird(@PathVariable("pathVariable") Integer num) {
   //some code
}

}
```

Assume that we have a simple Controller like that, and I am sending these requests  :

1) `/xxx/aaa/bbb/yyy/` -->okay it will be mapped with `getPageSecond` method and will do his work.

2) `/xxx/aaa/bbb/yyy/23` --> I think it must be mapped with `getPageThird` method, but it is strange that Spring is catching this request via `getPage` method.

I tried to dive into Spring codes to understand whats going on there, then i found **AntPatternComparator**. This comparator is giving result in order to bracket count, taking the lesser one for best match.

Why? Third one is more specific then others, is there something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You could manually add your own version of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` to your application context and set its `patternMatcher` property using `setPathMatcher(PathMatcher pathMatcher)` with your own implementation that will correct the issue you're having.

Comment: @Bart thanks for your response. i knew that i can configure it. but i want to understand why spring is deciding like that. it is dangerous for extending it i think.

Comment: @oko What do you mean by dangerous? What would you extend? You only need to provide your own `PatMatcher`.