# Spring SimpleUrlHandlerMapping: Pattern doesn't match URL

Tags: spring, url-mapping

I have the following mappping:

```
<bean id="controllerMappingProperties" class="java.util.Properties">
    <constructor-arg>
        <props>
            <prop key="/service/q-*-fltr-brand-_-*-find-html.html">redirectController</prop>
            <prop key="/service/q">queryController</prop>
            <prop key="/service/q-*.html">queryController</prop>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

So the URL

`http://localhost:8080/service/q-foo-fltr-brand-_-bar-find-html.html`

should map to the redirectController but it maps to queryController.

If I change the first mapping to

```
<prop key="/service/q-*-fltr-brand-_-bar-find-html.html">redirectController</prop>`
or
<prop key="/service/q-foo-fltr-brand-_-*-find-html.html">redirectController</prop>
```

the mapping works correctly.

Using two single stars in the pattern works with other mappings, so that can't be the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707136/path-priority-in-requestmapping/22709294#22709294) a few days ago. The problem lies in the `AntPatternComparator` which is used to sort the collection of matches paths.

In your case change your path from `/service/q-*.html` to `/service/q-**.html`. It does not make the most sense but it should work.

---

If you look at `RequestMappingInfo.getMatchingCondition`, the method for getting the matching conditions for the current request, you'll see the following comment which states that the best matching pattern will be first in the list.

*Spring 4 source*

```
/**
 * Checks if all conditions in this request mapping info match the provided request and returns
 * a potentially new request mapping info with conditions tailored to the current request.
 * <p>For example the returned instance may contain the subset of URL patterns that match to
 * the current request, sorted with best matching patterns on top.
 * @return a new instance in case all conditions match; or {@code null} otherwise
 */
@Override
public RequestMappingInfo getMatchingCondition(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // ...
}
```

The `AntPatternComparator` will basically rely on the amount of `*` and `{` present in the pattern. If their numbers are the same the pattern lengths will be compared. When sorting the collection of patterns with a `AntPatternComparator` your `/service/q-foo-fltr-brand-_-*-find-html.html` path will be greater then `/service/q-*.html` based on length. So `/service/q-*.html` will end on top.

Adding the extra wildcard makes `/service/q-**.html` the greatest since it's wildcard count is higher.

Comment: It works. But I would also like to know why. I hope somebody can answer this.